# npm i react-push-notification npm ERR

Tags: reactjs, npm

C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Table-of-the-day-v-2\app>npm i react-push-notification
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: app@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^17.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.8.0" from react-push-notification@1.3.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react-push-notification
npm ERR!   react-push-notification@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2021-10-08T15_15_54_627Z-debug.log

Answer (score 1):

it's because the package has react v16.8.0 as a dependency and you have installed react v17.0.2 you can use `npm i react-push-notification --force` and it will install it.